# Obfuscating code in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Under minifyEnabled I changed from false to true.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}
```

Then I generated a signed APK and used javadecompilers.com to see if files had been altered and the classes,variables, etc were still the same.

I also attempted to use dex2jar, but the terminal stated that no files were found. I also attempted to export my android studio project as a jar file.

Any other suggestions ?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to check? that the code was indeed obfuscated?

Comment: post your progaurd-rules.pro. Also try to use dex2jar https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar

Answer (score 0):

Did you build a release version of your application? As default for minifyEnabled is false, so if you build a debug version, that would explain it.

Other than that, could you post your proguard-rules.pro file? It might contain exceptions that are too broad.

I've used dex2jar many many times, and it's worked for me.
I'm on a mac, so i simply run "./d2j-dex2jar.sh app.apk" command, and then open the resulting jar file in a program called JDGui, there you can see all the files in the jar file.